# Help on a method to calculate date ranges

Tags: apex, business-logic

I want to calculate date ranges based on number of splits (called here nbr) between two dates. My Code works only for nbr equals to 1or 3;

```
getRangesBasedOnNumber (2, Date.newInstance(2022, 04, 01),Date.newInstance(2022, 12, 31) );
```

```
private static Map<Date,Date> getRangesBasedOnNumber (Integer nbr, Date dTStartGeneration, Date dTEndGeneration ){
       Map<Date,Date> result = new Map<Date,Date>();
       Integer period = (dTEndGeneration.month() + 1 - dTStartGeneration.month())/ nbr;
    system.debug('period '+period);
       for(Integer i =0 ; i< nbr; i++){
           Date startmonth = Date.newInstance(dTStartGeneration.year(),dTStartGeneration.month(),1);
           Date startDate = startmonth.addMonths(i*period);
           Date endDate = dTStartGeneration.addMonths(((i+1)*period)-1).addDays(date.daysInMonth(startDate.year() , dTStartGeneration.addMonths(((i+1)*period)-1).month()) - 1);
           system.debug('startDate '+startDate);
           system.debug('endDate '+endDate);
           result.put(startDate, endDate);
       }
       return result;
   }
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include more detail.  What happens with other values for `nbrVisites`?  Do you get an error message?  What result do you get and what value do you expect?

Comment: Hello @DavidCheng it is nbr, i don't have error. For Example if nbr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, if any one has the same requirement :

```
system.debug(getRangesBasedOnNumber (2, Date.newInstance(2022, 04, 01),Date.newInstance(2022, 12, 31) ));
```

```
public static Map<Date,Date> getRangesBasedOnNumber (Integer nbr, Date dTStartGeneration, Date dTEndGeneration ){
       Map<Date,Date> result = new Map<Date,Date>();
       Integer period = (Math.mod((dTStartGeneration.daysBetween(dTEndGeneration)/ nbr),2) ==0) ? (dTStartGeneration.daysBetween(dTEndGeneration)/ nbr) : (dTStartGeneration.daysBetween(dTEndGeneration)/ nbr)+1;
       for(Integer i =0 ; i< nbr; i++){
           Date startDate = dTStartGeneration.addDays(i*period);
           Date endDate = dTStartGeneration.addDays(((i+1)*period)-1);
           if (i == (nbr-1) && endDate != dTEndGeneration){
               endDate = dtEndGeneration;
           }
           result.put(startDate, endDate);
       }
       return result;
}
```